# Vue.js link interpolation in v-for

Tags: vue.js

I tried to find information in the vue documentation,but I didn't find this one . In this case, how can I pass information to {Icon} using vue js?

```
  <div class="weekfor">
    <h1>{{display(City)}}</h1>
    <div v-for="item of cast" :key="item.icon">
      <h1>{{item.Icon}}</h1> //output:'10d'
      <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{item.Icon}}@2x.png"> //must be output "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png"
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
<img :src="`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${item.Icon}@2x.png`">
```

Pay attention to `:` which is a shorthand to `v-bind:` before the src which means that you are binding an expression value to this property and not a string, which is your case, then you construct the string with string template and pass it using `${item.icon}`.

Comment: You're welcome! [vue.je guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) take a look at vue.je guide to learn more about the syntax of vue.